What was the time control of the 1960 WCC match between Tal and Botvinnik?
I'm reading Tal's great book "Tal - Botvinnik, 1960" right now. He does an excellent job in his annotations and even writes down how much time each player had after each move. However, I don't see a description of the actual time control anywhere.

Did the players have a certain amount of time to reach move 30? 40? 60?

I assume this is the pre-increment era, seeing as Fischer created the concept. But did they have delay of some sort on analog clocks?

When could adjournments be called?




Did the players have a certain amount of time to reach move 30? 40? 60?

The time control was 40 moves in 150 minutes (no increment) plus 60 minutes for each 16 moves after that until the game was decided with adjournment with a sealed move after 5 hours play.
These same time controls were used throughout the pre-digital FIDE era, roughly 1948 (5 player round robin) to 1993 (Kasparov and the PCA era). Source: this excellent answer by Remellion.

did they have delay of some sort on analog clocks?

No.

Thanks! And as someone who has never played with adjournment before, could you expand a little bit more on that aspect? Are you compelled to adjourn the game after reaching hour 5? Is it on white or black to adjourn? Or is it simply that the first person who wants to seal their move is the one who adjourns play?

@NoseKnowsAll Basically after they reached the first time control the players would make up the moves on their scoresheets if they had stopped writing moves with less than 5 minutes to go. Then they would normally be eager to seal a move, particularly an obvious one, so they could have their seconds start to analyse the game and tell them what to do next.
